# Sorting complexity

Tags: java, sorting, complexity-theory, bubble-sort

Given an array where values in the even indices are in incremental and values that in odd indices are in decremental order. For example:

```
[1,99,16,65,45,23,97]
```

I have thought about two different ways of sorting this:

1. Starting from i=0, j=a.length-2 and 
   comparing values of a[i] with a[j]. i+=2 if a[i] is smaller or j-=2 if a[j] is smaller. Need an extra array for that. Time is O(n) and space is O(n).
2. Reversing the order of the elements where their index is odd, and then bubble sort the entire array. Space is O(1).. what about the time?

Which is more efficient? What is the worst case time and space complexity for each? The bubble sort can takes a lot longer, no?

Comment: I guess if you try to improve your 1st algorithm a bit more you can reuse the same array (hence O(1) space) and still get O(n) time.

Comment: I tried to use a temporary variable to store the "about the be replaced" cell, but it got problematic, so I assumed it's not possible

Comment: What do you mean by problematic? What happened? Post your code if possible.

Comment: I don't have the code at the moment, but, for example: I start by comparing 1 and 23 -> 1 is smaller, so I push it to a[0] and now i=2. I keep 99 in "temp"  and keep comparing. When I'm moving on, the array is getting filled "faster" than comparisons, and the use of one temporary variable is not enough.. Maybe with two? I have no idea..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z9fD1Jhe

Comment: If you think you have an O(n) time, O(1) space solution, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to see a good use case for bubble sort in a real-world scenario. If you're going with option two, once you flip the cells in the odd indexes you have an array that may or may not be sorted on it's own right, and apply an O(n<sup>2</sup>) bubble sort. A trivial improvement would be to use quicksort or merge sort and get an O(n log(n)) time complexity.

Comment: In option two, the array isn't "nearly sorted"? (=O(n))

Comment: @Osh24 not necessarily. Consider something like the following: [900, 1000, 901, 950, 902, 1]. Even after half the indexes are flipped it isn't too appealing to bubble sort.

Comment: After flipping the odd indexes, we get [900 1 901 950 902 1000] and then it takes only 2 sorts to get this right, which is quite appealing, no?.. The question is, regarding this question and the way the array is constructed, could it be O(n) with bubble sort?

Comment: Anyway, that's what I managed to do: http://pastebin.com/z9fD1Jhe
Suggestions? I'm pretty sure it's O(n).